# DTO's properties equals entity's properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my project I have a service layer which receives a object from controller, turns it into a DTO and send it to a repository.
The problem I guess is that for every entity class in my project I would need a DTO with exactly the same properties of the entity.
Let me show some code:

```
public class PersonDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    };

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    };

    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Create(CreatePersonViewModel createPersonViewModel)
        {
            var personDto = //here I map createPersonViewModel to a PersonDto
            _personCreateService.Create(personDto);
        }
    }

    public class PersonCreateService
    {
        public void Create(PersonDto personDto)
        {
            _repository.Create(personDto);
        }
    }

    public class PersonRepository
    {
        public void Create(PersonDto personDto)
        {
            Person person = PersonMapper.Map(personDto);

            _db.Person.Add(person);
        }
    }
```

So, I have some questions about that:

1. Is it a good architecture?
2. Should I map dto to entity in service or only in repository?
3. Is there any problem making my dto equals my entity?
4. Am I stupid for not using dbContext direct in my controller as lots of tutorials teachs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer some questions.

1 - Is it a good architecture?

Maybe. If you are using an ORM tool such as NHibernate, Entity Framework, you have to think you could not share your transient objects from an ORM tool because sometimes you have a  proxy, not the concret type. I don't like to send to a view an object directly from an ORM tool. I prefer using a viewModel or DTO.

2 - Should I map dto to entity in service or only in repository?

Maybe, services should return the `ViewModel`, because is that the View needs, but sometimes you need to specify the result direct on the `Query` and takes it from `Repository`.

3 - Is there any problem making my dto equals my entity?

No, sometimes you can have an entity with 50 properties, and you need to show a grid on a View only with 5 or 6 properties, so, you have to create a ViewModel with these 5 or 6 properties and convert your entities to ViewModel type.

There is a nice tool called [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/), that could help you to map objects. You should consider using it.

There is a nice implementation of Jimmy Bogard with Asp.Net MVC and AutoMapper about how cleaning up posts and gets with ViewModel adopting best practices of object-oriented programming with asp.net mvc.

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/06/22/cleaning-up-posts-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: You can also use [EntitiesToDTOs](http://entitiestodtos.codeplex.com) to automatically generate DTOs and Assemblers from your EDMX file.

Comment: I know about AutoMapper, but I ask myself every day if it is really necessary to have a dto equal an entity. Current I use DTO but I think it's a bit boring.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. Imagine if you have a transient object (proxy) from an ORM and send it to your view, ok it can works fine but, imagine in your view you call a lazy property from your Entity, so, your view hits on database, so it is necessary to have a `ViewModel` becuase it should have ready everything the View needs to show that was processed by the controller. Is for this reason that there are tools like AutoMapper, EntitiesToDTO, etc...

Comment: @FelipeOriani That's exacly why I use DTO, to not display a entity class directly in view. In my projects I totally isolate the dal from my MVC project and only use DTO to transport between all layers. But I see lots os tutorials where they just use the dbContext in Controller and I don't understand why they do this shit  .

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Some tutorials on the web has only the didactic purpose, where tere is no a good separation of responsibilities, they just want to show how the technologies can work togheter. DTO/ViewModels/VO are nice to transport only the necessary to the View without the infra-structure of an ORM tool, or a distribuid layer. If you want to know more about architectures, I really recommend you to check this project -> http://sharparchitecture.net/ ... it has some good pratices of architecture of asp.net mvc with NH/EF, WCF, DDD, TDD etc..